# CommandButton & pageBlock title ignoring slds styling

Tags: visualforce, slds, commandbutton, pageblock

I have a Visualforce page using slds styling, and some of it works and some of it doesn't.

1. The pageBlock title does not have the shaded area around it - just displays the text in bold
2. The commandButton ignores the slds-button--brand styling when it's in a pageBlockButtons group. If I place it outside the buttons group, then it uses the brand styling.
   [image]
   What am I missing?

My VF page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" title="Verify Identity" extensions="AccountControllerExtension" sidebar="true" lightningstylesheets="true">
<apex:slds >
<apex:form id="pgForm">
    <apex:outputPanel id="spin">
        <div id="spinner" class="slds-spinner_container slds-hidden">
            <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--large" role="status">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account: {!account.Name}">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Back to Account" action="{!cancel}" style="margin-top: 5px;"/><br/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectRadio value="{!verifyOption}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="verify, spin, explanation,messages" action="{!verifyIdentity}"/>
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputPanel id="explanation">
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Not Required'}">
                    {!$Label.AMLNotRequiredExplanation}
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Manual'}">
                    {!$Label.AMLManualVerification}
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV'}">
                    {!$Label.AMLUsingEIV}
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel id="messages" rendered="{!NOT(showVerifyingMsg)}">
        <apex:pageMessages />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="verify" layout="none">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Key Information" mode="edit" rendered="{!verifyOption != null}">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Save and Submit for EIV" action="{!saveAndSubmit}" style="margin-top: 5px;" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV'}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')"/>
                <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Save Manual Verification" action="{!saveManual}" style="margin-top: 5px;" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Manual'}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')"/>
                <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Save Setting" action="{!saveNR}" style="margin-top: 5px;" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Not Required'}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV' || verifyOption == 'Manual'}">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Identity Consent" columns="1" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV'}" collapsible="false">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Identity_Consent__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Name" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.FirstName}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.LastName}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="National ID Details" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Detail__c.fields.Passport__c.InlineHelpText}" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Manual'}">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Passport"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acert.Passport__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Individual_does_not_have_Passport__c}" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV'}"/>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Detail__c.fields.Driver_License__c.InlineHelpText}" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Manual'}">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Driver License"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acert.Driver_License__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Individual_does_not_have_Drivers_Licence__c}" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV'}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Passport_Number__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Driver_Licence_Number__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Passport_Expiry_Date__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Driver_Licence_Expiry_Date__c}"/>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Version No."/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Driver_Licence_Code__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Address" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Street"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingStreet}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Suburb"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCity}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingState}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Post Code"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingPostalCode}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Country"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:slds>
```

Answer (score 1):

I played around some more and now have this below.

[image]
1: I removed the 'title' from the pageBlock section and added a div instead:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" rendered="{!verifyOption != null}">
    <div class="slds-box slds-text-heading_medium slds-size_full slds-theme_inverse slds-text-color_inverse">Key Information</div>
```

2: and when I remove the pageBlockButtons and replace it as below, the styling for the buttons works. I've placed this just above the closing  tag as the 'position' option is not available on a div.

```
<div class="slds-button-group slds-m-top--small slds-align_absolute-center" role="group">
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Save and Submit for EIV" action="{!saveAndSubmit}" style="margin-top: 5px;" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'EIV'}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')"/>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Save Manual Verification" action="{!saveManual}" style="margin-top: 5px;" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Manual'}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')"/>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand buttonclass" value="Save Setting" action="{!saveNR}" style="margin-top: 5px;" rendered="{!verifyOption == 'Not Required'}" onclick="document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove('slds-hidden')"/>
</div>
```